# Which dimensionless number would be appropriate for the given system?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis, navier-stokes

I'm designing an experiment for a multiphase system. The real system as shown has 2 fluids, liquid 1 and liquid 2 where liquid 1 is moving upwards due to momentum imparted on it by upward rising bubbles. In order to move upward it displaces the overlying liquid 2 radially as well as axially ( this is a cylindrical coordinate system ) ( * check the red arrows in the image )

Fig(a) is plume going upwards before hitting the above liquid 2.

Fig(b) is state after the plume strike liquid 2 and displaces it.

I want to ask that, which non-dimensional parameter I should take care of while selecting the fluids in the prototype. By which I mean, the physical properties like density, viscosity, surface tension, etc.

Given I know all the physical property of the real system!

I think it should be the Reynolds number, due to the inertial forces coming into the picture while liquid 1 is pushing liquid 2!

[image]

Comment: @ZeroTheHero where did I write about non-diagonal parameter?

Comment: I think it will be Reynolds number, but how to define the Reynolds number here?